# How do I fix ENOENT in the tmp directory when running tests on TeamCity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, teamcity, minitest

I have set up TeamCity to run tests for our codebase. Every now and then, some tests fail with `Minitest::UnexpectedError: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ dir_initialize`. This only happens in tests usin the `tmp` directory (cache or creating files there), and these tests fails stochastically (90+% of the time they are fine). I've never encountered this error locally.

I tried adding `mkdir tmp` to a console build step, but that just made the build fail as the directory existed. I wonder if TeamCity is messing with the directory in builds somehow. We're on Rails 4.2.11.1, Ruby 2.4.6, minitest 5.11.3 and TeamCity 2019.1.1

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this - any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What I have seen usually is that `/tmp` doesn't clear up locally even when the Rails server reboots. However, running on CI is different as they would be usually allocating different machines for each CI run. Some cases where the tests might fail:

1. If your tests directly depend on some files in `/tmp'.
2. If some of your tests depend on o/p of other test cases which generate files in `/tmp`

Remember that CI might be running your suite parallely on multiple servers, so that is one more thing to consider. This is the reason why running your tests randomly is considered a good practice.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, they're some helpful pointers. We do indeed have tests that rely on `/tmp` - the ones that are failing here. I don't think there are any "linked" tests, but I'll have a proper look. I'll look at refactoring or trying to ensure that `/tmp` is handled properly. Thanks!